# Facebook - "Proxied app is not already installed" during requestPublishPermissions

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, publish

I'm developing an android game with facebook integration. I can login using the Facebook Login Button and I can read the informations well. Then I want to ask for publish permissions, so I followed the Facebook guide:

```
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();   
    if (session == null || !session.isOpened()) {
        return;
    }
    List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();        
    if (!permissions.contains("publish_actions")) {
        requestPublishPermissions()
    }
```

and...

```
void requestPublishPermissions() {
    Log.d("main", "Requesting publish permissions.");
    final Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null) {
        Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSIONS)
        // demonstrate how to set an audience for the publish permissions,
        // if none are set, this defaults to FRIENDS
        .setDefaultAudience(SessionDefaultAudience.FRIENDS)
        .setRequestCode(AUTH_PUBLISH_ACTIONS_SCORES_ACTIVITY_CODE);
        session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
    }
}
```

The facebook page shows up, try to load something but then it closes itself showing nothing. And I obtain this error: "The proxied app is not already installed".

What is the problem? How can I resolve? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are logged in to your Facebook app in your mobile as the same user who owns the game app in Facebook? If the game app owner is different, you need to add the facebook user as a tester in the [facebook app developer console](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/). Of course for that both users have to be friends :)